# How to read i java rules loaded in optaplanner

Tags: java, optaplanner

Does anybody know how, I could extract using java rules currently loaded in a solver from a drl file?
This would be useful if the rule set changes frequently and should be stored in db along with the solution generated.

Context: an app similar to nurse rostering example.
- score is calculated using drools rules
- the rule set is in constant evolution
- when a solution is persisted in the db, it's difficult to figure out which exact rule set has been used to reach the solution
- it would be useful to store the actual rule set along with the solution

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `@ConstraintConfiguration` as used in the conference scheduling example and explained in the docs. Basically, if the `@ConstraintWeight` of some constraints are zero, those constraint are disabled.

That should solve your problem in a better. If it does not fit, please explain why you need to store the constraint rules (= code) in the database. Remember that constraint rules are domain specific, so any changes to the domain can break the compilation of the constraint rules.

PS: see also ConstraintStreams as an alternative to DRL.